# Evaluation of Dynamic Topic Models

Tags: gensim, evaluation, lda

I try to evaluate my dynamic topic models.
The model were generated with the gensim wrappers.
Are there any possible functions like perplexity or topic coherence equal to the "normal" topic modeling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there is topic coherence and perplexity for Gensim Wrapper:

```html
# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_ldamallet = CoherenceModel(model=ldamallet, texts=processed_docs, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
coherence_ldamallet = coherence_model_ldamallet.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_ldamallet)
```

You can check out this article for more information: [14](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/)

I hope this helps :)